# mvord with autorregresive structure

Tags: r, correlation, ordinals

This is my model:

```r
library (mvord)
roedores2 <- mvord(datos(IndicAD) ~ Trat + Tiempo + 
                    Trat:Tiempo+(1|Tiempo) + (1|Granja), data =  datos, 
                    error.structure = cor_ar1(~Tiempo), link = mvprobit(), 
                    control = mvord.control(solver = "BFGS"))
```

"IndicAD" is a ordinal variable with 0,1,2,3,4 as posible responses

"Trat" is a factor with 3 levels

"Tiempo" is a factor (repeated measurement over time) with 11 levels (times)

"Granja" is a factor with two levels (two sites of sample)

But I keep getting this error:

```r
Error in seq_len(rho$ndim) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(rho$ndim) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Comment: Please make the question reproducible

Answer (score 0):

The `mvord` package is working with multivariate ordinal regression with the meaning that response variable should contain more than one factor. In your case it is only one `indcAD` so `mvord` function fails.

In case you have two ordered factors `indcAD1` and `indcAD2` the algorith would work OK. In case you need to use univariate ordinal regression where response value is one factor you can use e.g. `polr` by `MASS` package.

```
library (mvord)
n <- 50
datos <- data.frame(
  IndiCAD1 = factor(sample(0:4, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE),
  IndiCAD2 = factor(sample(0:4, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE),
  Trat = factor(sample(3, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE),
  Tiempo = factor(sample(3, n, replace = TRUE)),
  Granja = factor(sample(2, n, replace = TRUE)))

res_mvord <-  mvord(MMO2(IndiCAD1, IndiCAD2) ~ Trat + Tiempo + 
                 Trat:Tiempo, data =  datos, 
               error.structure = cor_ar1(~Tiempo), link = mvprobit(), 
               control = mvord.control(solver = "BFGS"))


res_mvord
# Call:
#   mvord(formula = MMO2(IndiCAD1, IndiCAD2) ~ Trat + Tiempo + Trat:Tiempo, 
#         data = datos, error.structure = cor_ar1(~Tiempo), link = mvprobit(), 
#         control = mvord.control(solver = "BFGS"))
# 
# Thresholds:
#   $IndiCAD1
# 0|1       1|2       2|3       3|4 
# 0.0000000 0.7113659 1.0971497 1.7800162 
# 
# $IndiCAD2
# 0|1      1|2      2|3      3|4 
# 0.000000 1.088273 1.486173 2.135159 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept) 1    (Intercept) 2         Trat.L 1         Trat.L 2         Trat.Q 1 
# 0.7482449        1.2190449       -0.4892506        0.3545706        0.7432251 
# Trat.Q 2        Tiempo2 1        Tiempo2 2        Tiempo3 1        Tiempo3 2 
# -0.5710266        0.4844226       -0.6121860       -0.2728416       -0.3183369 
# Trat.L:Tiempo2 1 Trat.L:Tiempo2 2 Trat.Q:Tiempo2 1 Trat.Q:Tiempo2 2 Trat.L:Tiempo3 1 
# -0.5196205       -0.4058554       -0.4065644        0.6272309        0.3727869 
# Trat.L:Tiempo3 2 Trat.Q:Tiempo3 1 Trat.Q:Tiempo3 2 
# -1.6488805       -0.1636811        0.1608613 
# 
# Parameters of the error structure:
#   p25        p26        p27 
# 0.3447173 -0.3866346 -0.8193181 

res_polar <- polr(IndiCAD1 ~ Trat + Tiempo + 
                    Trat:Tiempo, data = datos)

res_polar
# Call:
#   polr(formula = IndiCAD1 ~ Trat + Tiempo + Trat:Tiempo, data = datos)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Trat.L         Trat.Q        Tiempo2        Tiempo3 Trat.L:Tiempo2 Trat.Q:Tiempo2 
# -0.84715296     1.26605745     0.72589772    -0.60879038    -0.74903326    -0.69633321 
# Trat.L:Tiempo3 Trat.Q:Tiempo3 
# 0.76901029    -0.09709166 
# 
# Intercepts:
#   0|1         1|2         2|3         3|4 
# -1.28052686 -0.05745217  0.58771283  1.71795395 
# 
# Residual Deviance: 150.1981 
# AIC: 174.1981
```